# Why BLToolkit inserts \0 instead of '@' symbol in generated queries?

Tags: c#, mysql, insert, crud, bltoolkit

I use BLToolkit with mysql and when I try to insert a record to a table, I am getting a query like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO `P`
(
    `Name`
)
VALUES
(
    \0Name
);
```

As you can see, this not the best mysql query.

Classes:

```cs
public class P
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [Identity]
    public int? ID  { get; set; }
    public string Name  { get; set; }
}
```

The code for inserting:

```cs
var p = new P();
p.Name = "asdf";
p.ID = (int) db.InsertWithIdentity(p);
```

Do you know, what is going on?

Comment: Does the query itself 'work'?

Comment: After replacing '\0' (in debugger, for example) - the query became correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through all the BLToolkit code, and do you know what I found??

The bug was in my MySqlDataProvider, I used an old version...

Here is correct: https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit/blob/master/Source/Data/DataProvider/MySqlDataProvider.cs

My error is here:

```cs
public static char ParameterSymbol
{
    get { return MySqlSqlProvider.ParameterSymbol;  }
    set { MySqlSqlProvider.ParameterSymbol = value; }
}
```

I haven't set the `MySqlSqlProvider.ParameterSymbol` property, my code just stored the value locally...